# laravel 5.5 and vue js not working out of box

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have compiled the assets and ran

npm install followed by npm run watch

using the example Vue file that comes build in I changed welcome.blade to

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <Example></Example>
    </div>

    <script href="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and also install Vue dev tools and nothing is viewing at all

Example.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

[What I get on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuMeG.png)

Comment: Does the console say anything? You didn't provide enough information to help you.

Comment: console is blank ,screen is also blank, there is simply no load at all , i have emptied the cache and hard reloaded

Comment: I've got the same problem with Vue, and in the console, I can see the error " [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
found in
---> <Example>
       <Root> "

Comment: ok, I solved my problem like this I used "import Example from './components/Example.vue';" then i used " Vue.component('example', Example);" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add 
`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>` before de `</body>` tag.

In this way to are adding the mix that contains the Vue library, components, and so much more.

I Hope this helps.